Quelle est la signification de « l' » dans « l'on a reçu » ?
Que remplace « l' » dans « l'on a reçu » dans la citation suivante :
Pour atteindre la vérité, il faut une fois dans sa vie, se défaire de toutes opinions que l'on a reçues, et reconstruire à nouveau et dès le fondement le système de ses connaissances.

Voir cet article.

C'est pour éviter: qu'on,  qui sonne comme con a reçu
